# What is the difference between the measure words 面 vs 张

Tags: grammar

Apparently both are measure words for flat objects, are they interchangeable or is there a difference to the types of flat objects they are used for?

Comment: see dictionaries, e.g. bkrs:  **张**   classifier for flat objects, sheet（用于纸、皮子等）:
一张纸 a piece (sheet) of paper
两张画 two pictures
一张银狐皮 a silver fox fur
五张铁板 five iron plates
（用于床、桌子等）:
一张床 a bed
四张桌子 four tables
七张犁 seven ploughs
（用于嘴、脸）:
一张笑脸 a smiling face

    **面**   classifier for flat surfaces such as drums, mirrors, flags etc 一面镜子  
三面红旗  
见过一面  （met once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 张 literally means 'extend'. It is a classifier for something with a thin, flat surface , typically in rectangular shape

**Typical objects with 张 as classifier**:

一张纸 = a sheet of paper

一张刀 = a knife (refer to the broad side of the knife)

一张桌子 = a table (refer to the surface of the table)

一张照片 = a photograph (which has a flat surface)

> 面 literally means 'face'. It is a classifier for something with a 'face-side'.  It can be in rectangular, oval, circular or other irregular shapes.

**Typical objects with 面 as classifier**:

一面镜子 = a mirror (only the face-side reflects image)

一面奖牌 = a medal plate (which has a face-side)

*雷达 (radar) has a 'face side', but due to its huge size ,  座 is used for its classifier, as in  一座雷达.*

*硬币 (coin) has a 'face side' but due to it's small size, 枚 is used for its classifier, as in 一枚硬币*

Comment: We say 一 *枚* 奖章.

Comment: Some objects can use different classifier according to other factors, 一面奖章 and  一枚奖章 are both acceptable, 一 枚奖章 is probably a small medal,  I would change the example to 一面奖牌 to illustrate the point more specifically

Comment: If a 奖牌  is very big and has a stand, the classifier can be changed to 一座. If a 奖章 is as big as a hand, it has to be called  一面奖章

Comment: 奖章/奖牌 are just small ones, so *一枚奖章/奖牌*. The bigger ones could be 奖杯，奖状， which is *一座奖杯* and *一张奖状* respectively.

Comment: I agree with @dan on 一枚奖牌 / 奖章

Comment: From https://www.hk01.com/%E5%A5%A7%E9%81%8B/36050/-%E9%87%8C%E7%B4%84%E5%A5%A7%E9%81%8B-%E6%9C%80%E5%A4%9A%E7%8D%8E%E7%89%8C%E8%83%8C%E5%BE%8C-%E8%8F%B2%E6%AF%94%E6%96%AF%E6%98%AF%E5%A5%A7%E9%81%8B%E6%AD%B7%E4%BE%86%E6%9C%80%E5%81%89%E5%A4%A7%E9%81%B8%E6%89%8B%E5%97%8E- *事實上，夏季奧運會中只有游泳和體操，讓選手有機會贏得那麼多**面**獎牌*

Comment: From https://udn.com/news/story/8296/2671655 ...  *在單日進帳八**面**金牌後，我國代表團也以廿六金、卅四銀、卅銅的九十**面**獎牌，名列獎牌榜第三名*

Comment: From http://www.epochtimes.com/b5/16/8/7/n8176330.htm  *里約奧運第十日，200多個國家及地區的代表隊從各項比賽中決出15**枚**金牌*。 The first two are from Hong Kong and Taiwan sites, this one is from mainland China site, it seems using 一面  or 一枚 as the classifier for 獎牌 depend on regions

Comment: @TangHo, it could be regional. In mainland China, you would always hear 一枚奖牌 from those official medias, like CCTVs. But I am also wondering if 枚 is used in TWN and HK as well?

Comment: Well, 八面金牌 sounds odd to me.

Comment: @Dan We always say  一面奖牌 when someone was awarded it. 一枚奖牌 is rarely heard in Hong Kong media. It is  acceptable to say 一枚奖牌 when we are talking about the medal itself, as a piece of object,  not associated to any event or people. My conclusion is, 面 in 一面奖牌 implies 'some meaning is contained in the medal' while 一枚奖牌 is just a piece of dead thing

Comment: @TangHo, interesting, do you say 八面金牌?

Comment: @dan Yes If someone won 8 gold medals in a sport event, we would say he won 八面金牌. We only say 八枚金牌 if someone is ordering them online for his sport souvenir collection. classifier 面 (face) implies the medal carries some substance or meaning, 枚(piece) just roughly describe the size and shape of the medal. Actually, If I said I have 八面金牌, you knew I won them myself; but if I said I have 八枚金牌, you knew I obtained them in any other way except actually winning them.

Comment: @TangHo, ah, good to know it. We always say 八枚金牌 no matter how you would get them. We won 8 gold medals in a sport event: 我们赢得了八枚金牌.

Answer (score 3):

**张 (zhang1)** is used for different objects, that may or may not be related with each other, e.g. sheets and flat furniture. If we really want to find a common denominator, I think that would be objects that are **spread open** [1]:

- 纸 paper (一张纸 a sheet of paper)
- 地图 map
- 照片 photo, picture
- 桌子 table
- 床 bed
- 木板 plank
- 脸 face （一张脸）
- 嘴 mouth （一张嘴）
- 弓 (gong1) bow （一张弓）

**面 (mian4)** is used for flat objects with a **face** or a **surface**:

- 镜子 mirror
- 旗子 flag
- 墙、墙壁 wall
- 鼓 drum
- 锣 （luo2) gong
- 盾 (dun4) shield

[1] that's not a dictionary definition. It's personal advice that hopefully makes enough sense to you to work as a reasonable rule of thumb.

Comment: I think this is the best distinction we could possibly get. There is no perfect rule of thumb for this indeed.

Answer (score 1):

面 as a measure word is used for only a handful of objects, 墙 镜子 鼓 and 旗 are all I can come up with. It stresses that the object has a flat surface.

张 indicates that the object is flat and **thin** (usually can be held with two fingers, like paper or cards), while 面 doesn't.

Usually they are not interchangeable.

Comment: 张 for thin objects overlooks 床 and 卓 which are very common occurrences

Comment: You are right. I forgot them.